# Provide home-screen icon for mobile firefox from web site

Tags: android, html, firefox, mobile

For the Chrome browser on Android

```
<link rel="icon" sizes="180x180" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
```

as well as for Safari on Apple devices

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
```

there are ways to tell the browser which icon to use when the user wants to place a bookmark/shortcut on the device's home screen.

Does anyone know positively that **Firefox on Android** supports something like this. At least the current version I have does not care at all for any of the two link-elements above.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, but in some rare cases FireFox offers no icon at all:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/favicon-196.png" sizes="196x196">
```

In case FireFox offers no icon I relaunch the browser and try again.
This also works for Chrome and should work for Apple devices which I haven't tested.
I use 196x196 because it is [suggested](https://github.com/audreyr/favicon-cheat-sheet) for Android's Chrome home screen icon.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox will use the image embedded in the favicon for all links save from the related website.

Currently there is no other way I am aware of to overide this functionality.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
```

Mozilla appear to be working a modernising the file icon in future releases.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=926139